# Angular 2 beta child component route-outlet doesnot work

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular2-forms

Here is my code

**unauthorised.ts**

```
import {Component, ViewEncapsulation} from 'angular2/core';

import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router, Location} from 'angular2/router';

import {HomePage} from '../../pages/homepage/index';


@Component({

    selector: 'unauthorised',

    template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',

    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,HomePage]


})

@RouteConfig([

    { path: '/', name: 'Home', component: HomePage, useAsDefault: true },



])

export class UnAuthorised {

}
```

**homepage/index.ts**

```
import {Component, ViewEncapsulation} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router, Location} from 'angular2/router';

import {HeaderHome} from '../../components/headerHome/index';
import {FooterHome} from '../../components/footerHome/index';
import {ContentHome} from '../../components/contentHome/index';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app/pages/homePage/index.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/pages/homePage/index.css'],
    directives: [HeaderHome, FooterHome, ContentHome]
})

export class HomePage {

}
```

What i am facing is router outlet is not filled with the content from hompepage ,i have done exactly as from the angular.io router navigation docs.can anyone tell me what is the issue with my code.
and i have all import provider for route in boot.

Comment: do you get any errors ? Is `unauthorised` tag present when you inspect in browser ?

Comment: How does your bootstrap function look like?

Comment: A_Singh yes in browser unauthorised and router-outlet are present

Comment: Can you also show how you have injected the ROUTER_PROVIDERS?